# Google Calendar embed alternative

Tags: calendar

I want to embed a calendar with events on my website. But I don't want to use google calendar. Are there alternatives?

**Requirements**:

- be hosted online by the company that owns the product (in other words, I don't want to host it myself)
- be able to add basic events
- be able to embed iframe into my own website

In a nut shell, I just want to embed a calendar with events for a small non-profit I am a member of, and I don't want to accept google's terms and conditions.

---

<sub>Here is the reason. I wanted to create a calendar for the small non-profit I am a member of, but I did not want this account to be associated with any of my existing personal accounts. So I did. The next day when trying to log in to this new calendar google told me basically "it appears this account should be associated with some other google accounts, but is not, maybe it was created by automated program, you violated our terms and conditions", in a nut shell. I have no idea how they figured this out. Hence, I am looking for alternatives because I don't want to accept their terms of conditions.</sub>

[image]

Comment: Question:  Do you know about Google Calendar API?  Using PHP (or another compatible language)  you can retrieve/add events programmatically.  Then you can display the results in any shape your willing to program.  Thus you can use an iframe, and your personal account can be hidden.

Comment: @cybernard API is not an option as we use weebly drag-and-drop hosting. Also, I don't want to waste time writing my own code. I just want service that just works.